# Alternatives for exec to get values of any variable

Tags: python

For debugging purposes I need to know the values of some variables in Python. But, I don't want create a dictionary with all variables and don’t want to add every new variable that I want to test at some point to a dictionary, especially when it comes to lists and their content, which is often procedurally generated.

So is there an alternative to just taking input as a string and then executing it by exec() or using print() and hardcoded variables?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Have a look at `eval()` and `locals()` functions in Python docs.

Comment: I have heard  from other programmers, that `eval()` is the same "dirty" solution as `exec()`. But `locals()` might be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You can use the locals() function to get a dictionary of all variables. For example:

```
a=5
b=locals()["a"]
```

Now b will get the value of a, i.e. 5.

However, while you can do this doesn't mean you should do this. There may be something wrong in the structure of your program if you want to access variables by using their name stored in a string.

Comment: I don't **need** to access the variables with their name in a string. But this is the only way I can think of to access every variable I'd like to check while the program is running without the need to restart it and add a print(variablexy) for example to the code. And many programmers say that `exec()` is quite a "dirty" solution. What I can fully understand.